# Need to Get the Index of Session using SAML2.0 to fix Logout

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm doing an agent SAML2.0 SSO using the code that is in this url:
http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/wso2-samples/sso_webapp/
but it does not work the logout. Excuse my English.
I am told, when the identity server sends responses of the authentication, sends a session index value in it and you need to return exactly the same value in the logout request to the identity server. How I can get the index value of the session with SAML 2.0?
This is the code of my class LogoutRequestBuilder
public LogoutRequest buildLogoutRequest(String subject, String reason) {
        Util.doBootstrap();
        LogoutRequest logoutReq = new org.opensaml.saml2.core.impl.LogoutRequestBuilder().buildObject();
        logoutReq.setID(Util.createID());

```
    DateTime issueInstant = new DateTime();
    logoutReq.setIssueInstant(issueInstant);
    logoutReq.setNotOnOrAfter(new DateTime(issueInstant.getMillis() + 5 * 60 * 1000));

    IssuerBuilder issuerBuilder = new IssuerBuilder();
    Issuer issuer = issuerBuilder.buildObject();
    issuer.setValue(Util.getProperty(SSOConstants.ISSUER_ID));
    logoutReq.setIssuer(issuer);

    NameID nameId = new NameIDBuilder().buildObject();
    nameId.setFormat(SSOConstants.SAML_NAME_ID_POLICY);
    nameId.setValue(subject);
    logoutReq.setNameID(nameId);

    SessionIndex sessionIndex = new SessionIndexBuilder().buildObject();
    sessionIndex.setSessionIndex(Util.createID());
    logoutReq.getSessionIndexes().add(sessionIndex);

    logoutReq.setReason(reason);

    return logoutReq;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If single logout is enabled in service provider registration in WSO2IS. Within the SAML response you get will contain the SessionIndex. 
        
So that value has to be stored somewhere to send back in the logout request.

This is an old sample you are using. [1] This document contain the sso sample which has single log out enabled.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+SAML2+SSO